# extract certain data from multiple excel files with R

Tags: r, excel

I import my data from multiple Excel files into R, and my data looks like this in R (there could be 100+ files each day):

```
> data
[[1]]
   ST Code Emp          Employee              Pay.Code Hours   Gross
1  AL 7229  65                 S                HOURLY  0.00    0.00
2  AL 7229  65                 S                SALARY  0.00 3060.00
3  AL 7229  65                 S              PER DIEM  0.00  765.00
4  AL 7229  65                 S EXPENSE REIMBURSEMENT  0.00   11.00
5  CA   42   2                 R                HOURLY 60.00  720.00
6  CA   42   2                 R              OVERTIME  3.25   58.50
7  CA   42   3                 A                HOURLY 80.00  800.00
8  CA   42   3                 A              OVERTIME  6.25   93.75
9  CA   42   4                 N                HOURLY 79.25  990.63
10 CA   42   4                 N              OVERTIME  7.00  131.25
11 CA   42   9                 P                HOURLY 32.00  352.00
12 CA   42   9                 P              OVERTIME  1.75   28.88
13 CA   42  10                 E                HOURLY 72.00  864.00
14 CA   42  10                 E              OVERTIME  5.00   90.00

[[2]]
   ST Code Employee Pay.Code    Gross
1 AL  7229       NA       NA  23954.0
2 AL  8380       NA       NA  11092.1
3  GA 7380       NA       NA  98142.0
4  GA 8380       NA       NA  11984.0
5  NC 7380       NA       NA 218129.0
6  NC 8380       NA       NA  27891.0
7  TN 7380       NA       NA  28441.0
8  TN 8380       NA       NA   8348.0
```

Now I'm trying to do is get `code = "7229"` as a single data set and export to a new excel file like this:

```
  > data

   ST Code Emp          Employee              Pay.Code Hours   Gross
1  AL 7229  65                 S                HOURLY  0.00    0.00
2  AL 7229  65                 S                SALARY  0.00 3060.00
3  AL 7229  65                 S              PER DIEM  0.00  765.00
4  AL 7229  65                 S EXPENSE REIMBURSEMENT  0.00   11.00
5  AL 7229  NA                                           NA  23954.0
6 AL  8380  NA                                           NA  11092.1
```

Is there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Is `data` a list of dataframes which you imported using something like `lapply(filelist, function(x) readxl(...))`?  If yes, then this is more a question about converting a list of dataframes into a single dataframe which you can filter on...

Comment: i solve my own problem :) just add rbindlist in my function will be ok, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list %>% 
  map_dfr(filter, Code == 7229) %>% 
  write_csv(path = "/INSERT/PATH/HERE/text.csv")
```

Here is the code with a reproducible example:

```
df_1 <- tribble(
  ~ST,  ~Code, ~Emp, ~Employee, ~Pay.Code,               ~Hours, ~Gross,
  "AL", 7229,  65,   "S",       "HOURLY",                0.00,   0.00,
  "AL", 7229,  65,   "S",       "SALARY",                0.00,   3060.00,
  "AL", 7229,  65,   "S",       "PER DIEM",              0.00,   765.00,
  "AL", 7229,  65,   "S",       "EXPENSE REIMBURSEMENT", 0.00,   11.00,
  "CA", 42,    2,    "R",       "HOURLY",                60.00,  720.00,
  "CA", 42,    2,    "R",       "OVERTIME",              3.25,   58.50,
  "CA", 42,    3,    "A",       "HOURLY",                80.00,  800.00,
  "CA", 42,    3,    "A",       "OVERTIME",              6.25,   93.75,
  "CA", 42,    4,    "N",       "HOURLY",                79.25,  990.63,
  "CA", 42,    4,    "N",       "OVERTIME",              7.00,   131.25,
  "CA", 42,    9,    "P",       "HOURLY",                32.00,  352.00,
  "CA", 42,    9,    "P",       "OVERTIME",              1.75,   28.88,
  "CA", 42,    10,   "E",       "HOURLY",                72.00,  864.00,
  "CA", 42,    10,   "E",       "OVERTIME",              5.00,   90.00
)

df_2 <- tribble(
  ~ST, ~Code, ~Employee, ~Pay.Code,    ~Gross,
  "AL", 7229,       NA,       NA,  23954.0,
  "AL", 8380,       NA,       NA,  11092.1,
  "GA", 7380,       NA,       NA,  98142.0,
  "GA", 8380,       NA,       NA,  11984.0,
  "NC", 7380,       NA,       NA, 218129.0,
  "NC", 8380,       NA,       NA,  27891.0,
  "TN", 7380,       NA,       NA,  28441.0,
  "TN", 8380,       NA,       NA,   8348.0
)

df_list <- list(df_1, df_2)

df_list %>% 
  map_dfr(filter, Code == 7229) %>% 
  write_csv(path = "/INSERT/PATH/HERE/text.csv")
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
     ST  Code   Emp Employee              Pay.Code Hours Gross
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <chr>                 <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    AL  7229    65        S                HOURLY     0     0
2    AL  7229    65        S                SALARY     0  3060
3    AL  7229    65        S              PER DIEM     0   765
4    AL  7229    65        S EXPENSE REIMBURSEMENT     0    11
5    AL  7229    NA     <NA>                  <NA>    NA 23954
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df = do.call("rbind", data)
```

Then you'll have all your data in a single dataframe which you can filter on:

```
df[which(df$Code == 7229),]
```